# Role scope is not working out of the blue on Devise sign in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, roles

I'm on Rails 7 and using Devise and Rolify...

I have a create an account page and earlier this week users were signing up just fine (I was dealing with some spam accounts) but I noticed that those spam accounts always chose the roles that were available to non-admin users which are the non-admin roles.

But today I noticed a spam account created that had the role of superadmin and I was thinking how is that possible and I found that all of my roles were visible to everyone.

This is also happening locally as well as my deployed site.

Luckily through Devise the user has to confirm their account before they can have access but unfortunately actual users are able to choose the superadmin role and then have access to do superadmin things, I'm keeping an eye on it now, but this is not safe at all!

In my roles.rb I have:

```
  ADMIN_ROLES = %w[SuperAdmin Admin Moderator Editor]
  scope :admin, -> { where(name: ADMIN_ROLES)}
  scope :not_admin, -> { where.not(name: ADMIN_ROLES)}
```

The scope is working in my Rails console when I enter `Role.admin` or `Role.not_admin` the appropriate roles show up.

On my registration page when I click on the role collection select dropdown all of my roles show up despite have the scope filter applied in my form:

```
<%= f.select :role_ids, Role.not_admin.sorted.pluck(:name, :id), 
          { label: "What roles does this user have??", 
            }, 
          { multiple: true, id: "select-dancestyle" } %>
          <% end %>
```

I did make a change to the page to make sure I'm editing the right form, I even tried removing the roles from the form and re-adding them, I also tried on a different browser just to make sure I wasn't running into any weird cookie issues, and I'm still getting all the roles appearing.

I'm not really sure what I'm missing of why that `not_admin` scope is not
registering on my form view. I am using the bootstrap form for gem for this form as well!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the order of the attributes I tagged, I was able to fix the issue by switching the code from:

```
<%= f.select :role_ids, Role.not_admin.sorted.pluck(:name, :id), 
          { label: "What roles does this user have??", 
            }, 
          { multiple: true, id: "select-dancestyle" } %>
          <% end %>
```

to

```
<%= f.select :role_ids, Role.sorted.not_admin.pluck(:name, :id), 
          { label: "What roles does this user have??", 
            }, 
          { multiple: true, id: "select-dancestyle" } %>
          <% end %>
```